# Profile Image of user commented on facebook post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

How can i retrieve the facebook post with the commnts and the profile pictures of the user through the single graph api call?

Answer (score 1):

You must use [batch requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) in order to do that, the first request gets the comment and the seconds uses its results to get the pictures.

You should provide the `batch` parameter with the request as following:

```
batch=[
    { 
        "method":"GET",
        "name":"get-comments","relative_url":"<SOME POST ID>/comments",
    },
    {
        "method":"GET",
        "relative_url":"?ids={result=get-comments:$.data.*.from.id}&fields=picture"
    }
]
```

Comment: It is giving this error                                                                                      Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: Array [HTTP 404]

Comment: `curl    -F 'access_token=MY_TOKEN' -F 'batch=[{ "method":"GET","name":"get-comments","relative_url":"MY_POST ID/comments",},{"method":"GET","relative_url":"?ids={result=get-comments:$.data.*.from.id}&fields=picture"}]'    https://graph.facebook.com/` works for me (with MY_TOKEN and MY_POST_ID replaced)

Answer (score 1):

No need to fetch the image if you have the `user_id` of the *commentor*.

The URL to get the profile picture is

> [http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser_id%7D/picture)

Infact, you can get three types of profile picture by using the graph API. That is,

> 1. [http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?type=small](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser_id%7D/picture?type=small)
> 2. [http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?type=square](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser_id%7D/picture?type=square)
> 3. [http://graph.facebook.com/{user_id}/picture?type=large](http://graph.facebook.com/%7Buser_id%7D/picture?type=large)

P.S: I guess the types are self explanatory.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the second (or more) call to graph api ?

Comment: @AviramSegal: no dude, you are just using the userid here on an img tag... btw cool profile pic...

Comment: Well I was assuming he wants to download the picture and not put it in an img tag. If you do want an img tag your way is better. and thanks about my pic :)

Comment: @AviramSegal: essentially every src also is a call :)

Comment: Well yes, but using your url is 2 calls (one to graph api which redirects to fbdcb), my example saves the first one. Anyway, I see there were enough votes to close the question...